# KeepAlive off for ajax request

Tags: apache, keep-alive

i need to turn off `KeepAlive` for ajax only i use this url `example.com/req/` in this path `/home/website/req/`

I tested this in apache2.conf but not work connection is keepalive

```
KeepAlive On
SetEnvIf Request_URI /req/ nokeepalive
```

Comment: Is it even possible to turn off KeepAlive after the first HTTP request on a connection? Think about what happens if the client first requests a page that *does* allow keepalive ...

Comment: Yes i need to KeepAlive only for refresh page with html, js, image, etc and after close connection for all `setTimeout` or ajax request